# Do any text editors for iOS and iPadOS support Markdown + Latex commands with preview?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ipados, latex, markdown

My requirements are a markdown editor for iOS which supports inline Latex syntax (and preview).

Limited Latex support is fine, full support is better, extensible is best. I’m looking for something better than Pages which supports a very small subset of Latex and has limited markdown support.

What free or paid options exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no", I've been looking myself.

[TexWriter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tex-writer-latex-editor-compiler/id552717222?mt=8) is a decent LaTex editor and preview but I don't know of a MarkDown one with inline LaTex.

Further, you might want to check out [Brett Terpstra's page devoted to iOS editors](http://brettterpstra.com/ios-text-editors/) for a great list of editors and keep an eye out for any that add "LaTex" as an extra feature.

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox paper](https:///paper.dropbox.com) works on iPads. Typing in $$ will start an inline latex environment.

Comment: **2021:** and Dropbox Paper is the best option I've found after trying Bear, Boostnote, Texpad and Ulysses. I wanted support for Markdown + Inline LaTeX with live preview, that syncs across MacOS and iOS devices.
 (Boostnote desktop does support MD+LaTeX but seems to have stopped providing  their ios app..).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) is a nice environment for using LaTeX and MD together, on iOS, iPad OS as well as many other platforms. Apart from fully supporting inline LaTeX formulas, it supports LaTeX code blocks via community plugins.

For example, I need to draw commutative diagrams in my notes, so I enabled a plugin called [TikZJax](https://github.com/artisticat1/obsidian-tikzjax). Now I can render not only complicated commutative diagrams, but also 2D or 3D plots, chemical figures using corresponding codes. Although my preferred diagram drawer, XY-Pic, is not yet supported in Obsidian, I still have this fully functioning replacement with code that I can easily copy to and from my LaTeX documents.

Answer (score 0):

[MWeb](https://www.mweb.im/) on iOS and macOS supports inline LaTeX Markdown extension. Inline LaTeX is rendered in the markdown preview.

> Markdown Assist: Useful Table insert and LaTeX writing aids.
>
> Markdown syntax: Supports Table, TOC, LaTeX, Fenced code block, Task lists, Footnote, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tre pro version of [Blockquote](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/blockquote-markdown-editor/id1396620426) is what you need. You can install the Free version and upgrade the app from inside. You need to configure the app for latex from your iPad settings.

Answer (score -3):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) plus the [Pandoc package](https://atom.io/packages/pandoc) appears to give you a large swath of the functionality of Latex and Markdown.

To get all of that working, you'll need to have Pandoc and Mac Latex installed already. When I have enough rep points to post more links, I'll provide references for these too!

Comment: The question is about solutions for iOS. Does Atom run on iOS?

Comment: Yes, Atom runs on iOS!

Comment: The link leads to a website offering a macOS download. Might be helpful to add a link to the App Store instead.

Comment: There is no atom for iPad or iPhone - if anyone can show otherwise please edit and flag this to prevent removal.